# Better way to only use callsuper in @EqualsAndHashCode and @ToString?

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring, lombok

I have class where I inheritage some fields, among them my id fields and those I difference on for the object.
I am using lombok to generate my @EqualsAndHashCode and @ToString, but only want to use my super class's version, and exclude all fields in my class.
I am wondering if there is a way to do that, without using the exclude and then add all fields.

My classes:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@ToString(of = { "id", "email", "name" })
@Data
public abstract class Resource {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Data
public class Employee extends Resource {
    private Organisation organisation;

    private List<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<Skill>();
}
```

Here I will get organisation and skills in my ToString, Equals and HashCode.

To exclude them I can use:

```
@ToString(callSuper = true, exclude = { "organisation", "skills" })
```

However as I have more fields than the example, and there might come more in the future, I would prefer if I could exclude all except for the ones from my super class.

I can also add one field in with the `of = {}`.

Is there any better way to accomplish that?

Comment: I haven't used lombock in a long time. but you could just remove the annotations from your employee class. that way there is no equlas and toString in your class and super is called automatically

Comment: That is true, I was using `@data` to get a few extra things, but if I remove data and add `@Getter` and `@Setter` instead, it gives a more clean view, which is the main goal :)
Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldn't simply

```
@ToString(callSuper = true, of = {})
```

work? Lombok knows nothing about the superclass fields (as this information is unavailable at the time it runs) and you can't include `id` or exclude `name`. All you can do is to make it call `super.toString()`. When you include no fields at all, then you get something like

```
Employee(super=Resource(43, Larvalis, larvalis@somewhere.com))
```

which may or mayn't be what you want. You could instead write

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName()
        + super.toString().replaceFirst("^[^(]+", "");
}
```

so you'd get just

```
Employee(43, Larvalis, larvalis@somewhere.com)
```

### Update:

The `of` parameter is obsolete in the meantime, see `onlyExplicitlyIncluded` in @Datz's answer.

Comment: Yes, somehow I had gotten into my head that I required at least 1 field inside `of = {}`. The solution is often more simple than you think :/

Comment: In fact it seems strange to explicitly set the default value `of = {}` - but yes, it is necessary for this solution. (The same for equals/hashcode methods.). I posted another solution which does not use the `of` attribute, which soon will be deprecated (see https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ToString.html#of() ).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using  `@ToString.Include` / `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` on the **id** field in the base class together with the class annotation `@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` / `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)`:

```
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public abstract class Resource {
    @Id
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer id;
    ...
```

The you can use `@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` / `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` on the child class(es):

```
@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Employee extends Resource {
    ...
```

The advantages:

- it is not necessary to explicitly set the annotations default values (`of = {}`) 
  (see @maaartinus answer)
- you can not forget to update the list of fields in the `of = {...} / included = {...}`lists
- you avoid the `of` annotation attribute which probably soon will be deprecated (see Javadoc).